# Mobx store doesn't trigger re-render on react-native project

Tags: react-native, expo, mobx, mobx-react

I've tried to learn how can I use MobX with React Native.
I tried to find some examples in GH but they are pretty old. (2-3 years old).

I want to write application on Expo Bare (ExpoKit), but I can't figure it out why my components do not rerender when I change MobX @observables.

I created a snack with my problem: https://snack.expo.io/@krasov/mobx-reproduction

Idk, may be i've misswatched documentation, but I can't figure out what the problem is here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were using MobX 6 then you now need to use `makeObservable` method inside constructor to achieve same functionality with decorators as with MobX 5 before:

```
import { makeObservable } from "mobx"

class Store {
  @observable string = 'Test String';
  @action setString = (string) => {
    this.string = string;
    console.log(`new value = ${this.string}`);
  };

  constructor() {
    // Just call it here
    makeObservable(this);
  }
}
```

Although there is new thing that will probably allow you to drop decorators altogether, `makeAutoObservable`:

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

class Store {
  // Don't need decorators now
  string = 'Test String';
  setString = (string) => {
    this.string = string;
    console.log(`new value = ${this.string}`);
  };

  constructor() {
    // Just call it here
    makeAutoObservable (this);
  }
}
```

More info here
https://mobx.js.org/migrating-from-4-or-5.html
and
https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves the problem. 
I used to watch MobX guides on YouTube and they are pretty old.